# MySQL PDO UNION query, finding the table the result came from

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, union

I'm trying to create a query that currently spans three tables looking for various ID's but I need to know what table the ID is coming from.

```
$searchQuery = 'LS7 2UP';

$stmt = $db->prepare("
SELECT id as 'nameSearchID' FROM user WHERE recordStatus=1 AND CONCAT( forename,  ' ', surname ) LIKE :nameSearch
UNION ALL
SELECT clientID AS 'salesOrderClientID' FROM salesOrder WHERE recordStatus=1 AND salesOrderID LIKE :salesOrderID
UNION ALL
SELECT id AS 'addressID' FROM address WHERE recordStatus=1 AND postcode LIKE :searchPostcode
");

$stmt->bindValue(':nameSearch', "%$searchQuery%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':salesOrderID', "%$searchQuery%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':searchPostcode', "%$searchQuery%", PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute();
$rowCount = $stmt->rowCount();
$resultsOrig = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This outputs 2 results which *it is* finding from the address table, but it's showing as coming from the '**user**' table.

Any ideas?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [nameSearchID] => 69e17996-93be-4562-ad55-49ac62801bba
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [nameSearchID] => 135e4e26-869d-44cc-b400-383e884923ea
        )

)
```

Comment: Fixed it!

$stmt = $db->prepare("
select 'user' as user, id from user WHERE recordStatus=1 AND CONCAT( forename,  ' ', surname ) LIKE :nameSearch
union all
select 'salesOrder' as salesOrder, clientID from salesOrder WHERE recordStatus=1 AND salesOrderID LIKE :salesOrderID
union all
select 'address' as address, id from address WHERE recordStatus=1 AND postcode LIKE :searchPostcode
");

Answer (score 0):

Add it as Parameter:

```
SELECT id as 'nameSearchID', "user" FROM user WHERE recordStatus=1 AND CONCAT( forename,  ' ', surname ) LIKE :nameSearch
UNION ALL
SELECT clientID AS 'salesOrderClientID', "salesOrder" FROM salesOrder WHERE recordStatus=1 AND salesOrderID LIKE :salesOrderID
UNION ALL
SELECT id AS 'addressID', "address" FROM address WHERE recordStatus=1 AND postcode LIKE :searchPostcode
"
```